# What's wrong with this implementation?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    int count = 0,i=0,j=0;
    string str,a,b;
    //a.reserve(100);
    //b.reserve(100);
    char ch;
    cin>>str;
    int length = str.size();
    cout<<length<<"\n";

    if ( length % 2 != 0 )
        cout<<"-1"<<"\n";
    else
    {
        while ( count < (length/2) )
        {
            a[j] = str[i];
            j++,i++;
            count++;
        }

        a[j] = '\0';
        j = 0;

        while ( count < length )
        {
            b[j] = str[i];
            j++,i++;
            count++;
        }

        b[j] = '\0';
        cout<<a<<"\n";
        cout<<b<<"\n";
        cout<<str<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On running this code, why doesn't it divide the string into two parts? I wanted to divide a string having even number of characters into two parts but when I print the output, it shows nothing except the original string. Why does this happen?

Comment: You could use [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)

Comment: Before you execute the line `a[j] = str[i];`, how big is string `a`?

Comment: The code doesn't even *compile* - where are `i` and `j` declared and initialised, for example ?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. It will compile now. :)

Comment: @user3769571 A string class would stink if it didn't have member functions that took portions from the string.  Meaning this -- you're reinventing what `substr` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you are missing the declarations of `i` and `j`. You probably forgot to include them in the posted code. I am going to assume that you have:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
```

In the code that separates the string, you have:

```
  while ( count < (length/2) )
  {
     a[j] = str[i]; // NOT GOOD.
     j++,i++;
     count++;
  }
```

By assigning to `a[j]`, you are accessing out of bound memory and invoking undefined behavior. You can change that block of code to:

```
  while ( count < (length/2) )
  {
     a.push_back(str[i]);
     j++,i++;
     count++;
  }
```

and it should work. The same goes for the `while` block following the above lines. You can use

```
  while ( count < length )
  {
     b.push_back(str[i]);
     j++,i++;
     count++;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code won't compile as `i` and `j` aren't defined.  But you simply want something like:

```
size_t len = str.size() / 2;
if (str.size() == len * 2) {
    string a(str, 0, len);
    string b(str, len, len);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code simply shall not be compiled because variables `i` and `j` were not defined.

EDIT: As you updated your code then you may not use the subscript operator with empty strings `a` and `b`. And there is no need to append the strings with the terminating zero.

The code could look the following way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s;
    std::string t1, t2;

    std::getline( std::cin, s );

    if ( s.size() % 2 == 0 )
    {
        t1.reserve( s.size() /2 );
        t2.reserve( s.size() /2 );

        for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s.size() / 2; i++ )
        {
            t1.push_back( s[i] );
            t2.push_back( s[s.size()/2+i] );
        }

        std::cout << t1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << t2 << std::endl;
        std::cout << s << std::endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

If the input is:

```
Hello world!
```

...then the output will be:

```
Hello 
world!
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get compilation error on running the same program, i and j are not declared anywhere in the program.

You should declare i and j in else scope so they the value remains same in both the while loops, if you declare it in while loops value again becomes zero in other while loop.